# how do i confirm fixed tomcat servlet?

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I'm studying Tomcat architecture. I wanted to fix org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet and confirm its result.
For example i add the following code in JspServlet.java init() method.

```
    FileWriter test = new FileWriter("c:\\worktest.txt");
    test.write("test!!");
    test.close();
```

After edit code, compile it and repackage jasper.jar file. And then I replace old jasper with new thing. of course restart tomcat.

I think that adding code will work and write text file in C drive. But result doesn't exist.
I've already check .jsp file, but it doesn't have any problem. because of creating JAVA and CLASS file.

There's something wrong with my way?

Comment: StackOverflow generally aims towards more practical programming problems. As to the architecture of Jasper, I suggest looking at the [Tomcat mailing lists](http://tomcat.apache.org/lists.html). Just a friendly suggestion – you are not off-topic here but you might get more information there.

Comment: Also: Just a wild guess, but your problem may be a security restriction. Servlets are generally sandboxed, restricting their access to certain folders but not the entire disk. I see you are accessing the root level of C drive. Check Tomcat’s logs to find security violation errors being reported.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't know about restriction of topic. I will comply with it. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: No, no, I was not forbidding the topic; forbidding is not my role here anyways. I said you are not necessarily off-topic for StackOverflow. I'm just suggesting that if you want detailed info about the internals of Tomcat, searching their email archives and possibly posting on the Tomcat mailing lists may prove more useful than posting here.

Comment: @BasilBourque, thank u. I will contact to them. and I didn't solve this problem. So I update tomcat version. So it works well. I think problem is tomcat configuration or unknown things